# Binary Tree with inequalities,AND, and power

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I am trying to write an **algorithm** for presenting the below **mathematical expression** in a **binary tree** in order to present the **post fixed** and **prefixed** expression.

[image]

I know the **precedence levels** of common used operators, and i know how to deal with normal mathematical expressions, but i am not familiar with the use of inequalities like **< >=** , add for that the use of **AND**.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator precedence usually goes

`arithmetic` > `equality` > `logical`

so the `<` and `>=` would evaluate before the AND.

Treat them like normal arithmetic operators when building the parse tree but give equality operators lower precendence than arithmetic, and logical lower than that.

for example [check the java operator precendence](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html)

Comment: thanks for the support, what is the precedence level of the power, like the 2k of (a+b) and can i deal with the 2k like 2*k or 2k as one block?

Comment: if you are looking at the java table, exponents would be a 12.5. Exponents are calculated before binary arithmetic operators. When evaluating (a+b)^2k, remember you have to evaluate the exponent as an expression. So you first evaluate some exponent function, in this case `2k`, and then you evaluate the base raised to the exponent